# Why is my 180v dc motor circuit not working?

Tags: dc-motor

I bought a "Johnson" treadmill motor that I know works well, it's 180v, 10amp, 2.5hp.
I decided to go with the cheap setup, so I powered it through a 10000w 80amp max scr, going through a full bridge rectifier.
I have wired it correctly but every time I switch it on it blows the fuses. Could anyone give me any ideas as to why?
I am fairly sure it is not a short circuit.

Comment: Please make a diagram of your circuit or else we are left to assume everything.

Comment: If it blows the fuse without the motor you have some issue with your circuit or the implementation. Otherwise the fuse may be inadequate. Hard for us to tell with no schematic and no photos.

Comment: What is the starting load of that motor? And what fuses?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't know how to begin drawing a schematic.

Comment: There's a tool for that when you **Edit** your question.

Comment: Could you  advise me on the best way to control such a motor? I have the original board but have no idea how to modify it 

Comment: And to all that have commented, I really do appreciate your feedback. I am not electronically minded, I was hoping this would be a simple project, it has become a bit of a nightmare trying to find an affordable way to control the motor.

Comment: *Could you advise me on the best way to control such a motor?* Yep, with a suitable motor controller. For such a strong motor that might be some "professional" device with a "professional" price tag. Also, I am an experienced EE yet I would not mess with such a powerful motor **at all**. I would buy a ready-made setup of get an experienced professional to do it properly. I do not believe that what you want can be done "cheap".

Comment: The motor is from a treadmill, and can be powered by the board.

Comment: Problem with this, I don't know how to do it, guess I will have to find someone who has done it before. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It sounds like you have an AC supply feeding a bridge then the DC motor - what AC supply is it?

Comment: You really need to draw a schematic.

Answer (score 1):

You were wise to put in a fuse.

Without getting too deep into motor theory, consider that for a DC motor, the motor speed is proportional to voltage and the torque is proportional to current. Your motor will run at your voltage - the problem is getting up to speed.  When you apply the voltage, the motor is static, and must accelerate up to its end speed.  This acceleration requires torque, and since you are applying full voltage, the motor "tries" to accelerate quickly, drawing high current and blowing that (blessedly installed) fuse.  A good controller, as @Bimpelrekkie suggests, will control the maximum current to the motor to keep it in the reasonable torque range until it gets up to speed.  Once it is at speed and the inertial load is stable, the current will be reduced to that required to do whatever work you are trying to do.  Without a controller, you can have large fluctuations in current whenever the load changes.